# Benefits of using a windows-domain

Tags: networking, active-directory, workgroup

We are a small business 5-10 employees, and would like to know what are the major benefits of moving from a simple network/WORKGROUP to a windows-domain.

Thanks

Comment: Possible dupe: http://serverfault.com/questions/204096/domain-vs-workgroup

Comment: John, I've noticed that you're new, and all three of your questions so far are not very good. Please take a minute to read the [faq] ans [ask]. This site is a valuable resource, but please use the search function before asking and make sure your questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

In a small network like yours, you may not notice the importance of using domain controllers.

However, you will find it really essential to have centralised management/control of your computers when the network becomes larger.

Windows domain controllers provide very powerful control over your network computers as opposed to workgroup. In the latter, you need to control each computer by its own.

Comment: Is Microsoft Exchange directly connected with windows-domain?

Comment: Email users can be authenticated against active directory. So, they are related.

Comment: What is considered a large network?

Comment: There is no strict number. You can say above 10.

Comment: So lets say for just 10 users, do you think it is a good investment to buy SBS 2011 standard + additional cals?

Comment: SBS 2011 is a good investment and is targeted to companies like yours: 5 users, 10, users, etc. up to 75 users. If you don't need Exchange Server or Sharepoint then SBS 2011 Essentials may be a good fit, for up to 25 users.

Comment: +1 It's really more than just the number of people. It's manageability, security, integration, deployment, and a number of other factors. Larger organizations need these things to stay sane and efficient. Smaller businesses can get away with less than ideal situations. The line is usually somewhere in the 10 to 25 employee range, but each situation is going to be different.

Comment: What @ChrisS and Khaled said. If I were in a situation where I had 5 or more PCs and the resources available to run AD, it's a no-brainer to me. I'd run AD.